# Term for one culture having a large influence over surrounding cultures?

Tags: cultural-history

Is there a somewhat established term for one culture (not state) having a comparatively large influence over surrounding/neighboring cultures?

I’m not talking about the volitional political or military influence or control of a country, where the terms *hegemony* or *soft power* (“when one country gets other countries to want what it wants”) come to mind. Rather, I mean when surrounding cultures voluntarily imitate, adapt, import and include the fashion, architecture, technology and ways of thinking and writing of the other culture, even if this is not desired or especially promoted by said culture. (Of course, military power may very well preceede the phase I’m looking for. And in turn the phase I’m looking for may very well preceede becoming a soft power. But neither are necessary.)

Examples in the West are probably the Roman Empire (vis-à-vis the Germanics), the Catholic Church and later the French and then British high societies, as well as the American Way of Life after WW2. Or the influence of Chinese culture over surrounding peoples.

Comment: I think that is the definition of soft power. Cultural imperialism has been used in this context.

Comment: yeah maybe.. it's just that _soft power_ seems to me to have an agent (i.e. it is done actively to promote the power) and that agent is necessarily a country...

Comment: ["A defining feature of soft power is that it is noncoercive;. . . "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_power) - to me, that conveys that it is exercised without agency.  I'm also skeptical that  _if_ an agent exists that it must be a country. You cite the Catholic church; a strong argument could be made for Islam, or for "Liberalism", or "communism" or "consumerism",   I think I understand your assumptions, but I think you're splitting a hair that doesn't need to be split.

Comment: This might be a better fit for e.g. English Language or Politics SE.

Comment: Contrary, ["The term "soft power" -- the ability of a country to persuade others to do what it wants without force or coercion -- is now widely invoked in foreign policy debates. "](https://www.foreignaffairs.com/reviews/capsule-review/2004-05-01/soft-power-means-success-world-politics) implies the agency you posit.  Interesting.  Rather an interesting debate, but I'm not sure that we're still discussing history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on the English Language site.

Comment: The question can be edited to fit History SE by merely asking for historical examples. Voted against closing.

Comment: Hammers, nails, gentlemen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One term to describe this is [cultural diffusion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/culture-diffusion).

> "The spreading out of culture...from a central point."

Today's "central point" might be America or China; Britain or France during the Industrial Revolution, and Greece or Rome in ancient times.

Comment: good find! will accept if nothing else comes along...

Comment: @mb21: Yes, I like to wait a day or two before accepting.

Answer (score 4):

One term that comes to mind is [Acculturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acculturation). You mentioned a larger culture influencing smaller surrounding cultures and that is more or less the definition of acculturation. It's not necessarily a forced effect, but rather through contact between the cultures, the larger culture tends to "assimilate" the less dominant cultures into it.